# Export unicode characters for package

Tags: r, unicode

I made a function that removes en and em dashes. Great! But when I try to upload it to github and then re-install as a package something happens to the function. It replaces the dashes with some gobly gook characters. That usually means unicode stuff.  I want to be able to export the function.

I tried replacing `\\–` with `\u2013` and `0x2013`.  Also played with `fixed` and `perl` arguments.  No luck.

***Here's:***

1. the function that works
2. a test case
3. how it looks after I import it back in

**Code:**

```
#What I exported
incomp <- function (text.var){
    x <- gsub("\\–", "|", x)
    x <- gsub("\\—", "|", x)
    return(x)
}

#here it is in action working well
x <- c("I like...", "well?.", "–", "—")
incomp(x)

#[1] "I like..." "well?."    "|"  "|"   #what I look like (ain't I pretty?)

#what the exported function looks like when the package compiles
incomp <- function (text.var){   
    x <- gsub("[â€“]", "|", x)
    x <- gsub("[â€”]", "|", x)
    return(x)
}

#I don't work anymore
x <- c("I like...", "well?.", "(–", "—")   #I'm broken
incomp(x)
```

A search for r and unicode brings up lots of information but I can't seem to apply it to my situation correctly.

***[The unicodes are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash):***

- u2013 for the en dash
- u2014 for the em dash

This post is cross posted at talkstats.com.  I generally do not cross post but am under the gun to get this out.  I will link the two threads.  [LINK TO THE TALKSTATS THREAD](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/26185-Special-characters-for-a-package)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default when exporting locale of R are set to "C" I guess. Your locale maybe different.
Perhaps you can use Sys.setlocale in your package?